# CSS Animation based on 2d transform functions in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webkit, css-transforms, css-animations

I have a simple loading animation that involves rotating a div with a background image. For whatever reason, the animation functions flawlessly in Chrome and Safari, but fails to animate in Firefox. Additionally, when viewing the element in the inspector no animation property is shown, leading me to believe Firefox is rejecting the property based on its syntax. The syntax  is W3C standard as far as I know. Here's the keyframes codes:

```
@keyframes spin{
0%{ transform: rotate(0deg);}
100%{ transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin{
0%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin{
0%{ transform: rotate(0deg);}
100%{ transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
```

And this is the selector code:

```
animation: 'spin' 2s linear 0s infinite;
-webkit-animation: 'spin' 2s linear 0s infinite;
-moz-animation: 'spin' 2s linear 0s infinite;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing ' ' from `'spin'`, like this: `animation: spin 2s linear 0s infinite;` fixes it.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xwp9V/)

***EDIT:*** I may also add that you should put the unprefixed version last, as seen in my demo.

```
-webkit-animation: spin 2s linear 0s infinite;
   -moz-animation: spin 2s linear 0s infinite;
        animation: spin 2s linear 0s infinite;
```

Comment: Indeed.  Per spec, the animation name in the `animation` property is an identifier, not a string.  WebKit has a known bug where it also accepts strings.

Comment: Ah, so it's a bug. I didn't know that. But I thought it was odd that it worked in WebKit browsers.

Comment: Realized the other problem was that I had the unprefixed version at the top of the stack instead of the bottom.